# How to convert Figma design to HTML5/CSS?

Tags: html, css, django, figma

I am making an app using Django and Python and I want to integrate some Figma designs with my web application. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Since django app uses `HTML5` to render web pages, the question should be specifically for `HTML5` and `CSS` not django.

Comment: The answer is, you have to recode them manually as html. Figma and html/css are different and have their own subtle needs. The figma dev mode allows some cool help with css though

Answer (score 0):

Figma recently released a new update - dev mod. https://www.figma.com/dev-mode/

In it, you can copy the HTML code of some elements.

video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbW2bS7quPw